# swscanf can't read integer value

Tags: c++

```
    std::wifstream ifstream("JobList.txt");
    ifstream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    if (!ifstream.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "파일을 찾을 수 없습니다!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }


    std::wstring s;

    wchar_t name[20];
    int priority{};
    int workingTime{};
    int requestTime{};
    while (ifstream) {
        std::getline(ifstream, s);

        swscanf(s.data(), L"%[^',']s, %d, %d, %d", name, &priority, &workingTime, &requestTime);
            
        mRequestArrivationQueue.emplace(name, priority, workingTime, requestTime);
    }

    ifstream.close();
```

This is JobList.txt file

```
Good Boy, 1, 2, 5
도서 대출, 1, 2, 13
```

swscanf read only first wstring(name), but it doesn't read rest integer values

Comment: This is not `C`

Comment: @rryker I'm sorry , I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a little error in your code and a terrible (even if common) *bad practice*.

The error in that the conversion format specifier **is** `[set]` and it shall not be followed with a `s`. Here the format string *requires* a `s` character afer the first field (which is impossible) so the conversions stops after decoding the first field. The fix is trivial, remove that offending `s` (and the useless quotes, thanks to @AdrianMole for his comment):

```
    swscanf(s.data(), L"%[^,], %d, %d, %d", name, &priority, &workingTime, &requestTime);
```

And the terrible practice is to fail to test the return value of a `scanf` family function. Had you tested it, you would have immediately found that it was 1 and that only the first field had been decoded.

IMHO, unless you are a C programmer and have used the C io functions for a long time, you should better use a C++ `[w]stringstream`. The syntax is not easier, but error detection is better...

Comment: Another (probable) mistake is the single quotes in the `%[^',']` set - these are taken as part of the set and input of the name will stop should there be a `'` in the string. Should be just `%[^,]`. (A name like Patrick O'Connell, for example, would cause this problem.)

Comment: @AdrianMole: Thanks for your comment. I have included it into my answer...